# Exclude provided date with git log --since

Tags: git, git-log

I'd like to exclude commit done at the provided date from the git log --since  command.

When running :

```
 git log --since "2014-04-10 13:23:51 +0200" --pretty=format:" %ci, (%h): %s"
```

I get:

```
 2014-04-10 17:00:22 +0200, (2697ef4): commit message 2
 2014-04-10 13:23:51 +0200, (8170ee5): commit message 1
```

But I'd like to exlude the second one since the commit date is exactly the provided date and get only:

```
 2014-04-10 17:00:22 +0200, (2697ef4): commit message 2
```

Comment: You can use `git log --since "2014-04-10 13:23:52 +0200" --pretty=format:" %ci, (%h): %s"`, right? just incrementing the second by 1? Or are you needing this because of some automation tasks?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) says that `--since` should exclude the passed date, so I'm not exactly sure what it's not working in your case.

Comment: @mu無, yes this is for automation tasks (automated builds): I'd like to generate a log file from all the commits since the last build. I use the date of the last commit of the previous build in the git --since command, and I'd like to exclude this commit since it is related to the previous build and not to the current one.